# Why integration of $\dot{x}\ddot{x}$ is equal to $4\dot{x}^2$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I know how to calculate the basic integral such as $x$ or $x^2$ but I don't understand why the integral of  $\dot{x}\ddot{x}$ is equal to $4\dot{x}^2$.

I know this is a very elementary question but can someone teach me the integration process?

Comment: It isn't. A primitive of $x'x''$ would be $\frac12(x')^2$.

Comment: can you write what you are claiming explicitly? why not use integral and dx notation to keep it clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Integrate $\dot x \ddot x$ w.r.t the variable $t$:
$$I=\int \dot x \ddot x dt=\int \dot x \dfrac {d\dot x}{dt}dt=\int \dot x d \dot x$$
Finally you get :
$$I= \dfrac {\dot x^2}2+C$$